# twitter bootstrap datepicker assign to a field

Tags: jquery, datepicker, twitter-bootstrap

Hi i have a questions about this http://dl.dropbox.com/u/143355/datepicker/datepicker.html twitter bootstrap plugin.

How to change this code so I could asign datepicker to field which I want ?? I have tryied like this

```
$('[data-datepicker]').each(function(){
   new DatePicker(this, option);
});

new DatePicker($('#date'), options);
```

And every time a get `Datepicker is undefined`. How to make it work ??

Comment: Please, 1 question per question.

Comment: Did you use that `<script src="bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>` ? If so, check the path, to be sure that your browser has access to it.

Comment: when i Use it like in http://jsfiddle.net/skowron_line/tzrPG/1/ its ok but when I comment `$(function() {
    $(selector).datepicker();
    $('html').click(clearDatePickers);
  });` this and try to use it like i wrote I get error

Comment: are you using this datepicker? http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

Comment: @baptme no link to this plugin is in my first post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use`Datepicker` because it's enclosed in the plugin *namespace*.
You should use that :

```js
$('#date').datepicker(options);
```

and remove the `data-datepicker` attribute like that :

```html
<input id="date" type="text"/>
```

---

For everybody information, this is the **source of the plugin** : https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/657